# Getting data from multiple data sources

Tags: go

I'm new to Golang and don't know how to solve the issue below.

**The issue.**

I have multiple data sources. Each data source can return data or nil. I need to get data from the first who will return data and don't wait others. The simplest solution is to ask data sources one by one but it's not very good solution.

**Use case.**

There are three data sources: `A`, `B` and `C`.

`A`: has no data & very fast

`B`: has data

`C`: has no data & very slow

There is a `Repository` which aggregates all data sources.
When I call `repository.fetchData()` it should concurrent ask all data sources for data and when it'll receive data from the `B` data source it should not wait for the `C` and just return.

The code snippet (which is not work as I want):

```
type Data struct{}

type DataSource interface {
    GetData(id int) *Data
}

type repository struct {
    dataSources []DataSource
}

func NewRepository() DataSource {
    return &repository{
        dataSources: make([]DataSource, 0),
    }
}

func (r *repository) GetData(id int) *Data {
    ch := make(chan *Data, len(r.dataSources))
    defer close(ch)

    for _, dataSource := range r.dataSources {
        go func(ds DataSource) {
            ch <- ds.GetData(id)
        }(dataSource)
    }

    var result *Data
    for data := range ch {
        if data != nil {
            result = data
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

**The questions:**

1. Could you please give me advice or code snippet (it's better) how to solve the issue.
2. What is the name of the pattern?

Comment: The code you show fits your description. Why doesn't it work as you want?

Comment: Because it can send data to closed channel. If data source B will return data then the function returns and closes the channel. After that data source C can write to closed channel.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. I have commented out the code for easy understanding.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var Deadline = errors.New("deadline")

type Sourcer interface {
    Fetch() []byte
    Name() string
}

// Source implements Sourcer.
type Source struct {
    Src   string
    Data  []byte
    Timer time.Duration
}

// Fetch fetches from the source with a specified delay.
func (s Source) Fetch() []byte {
    <-time.After(s.Timer)
    return s.Data
}

// Name returns the name of the data source.
func (s Source) Name() string {
    return s.Src
}

// NewSource returns a new initialized source.
func NewSource(name string, data []byte, timer time.Duration) *Source {
    return &Source{Src: name, Data: data, Timer: timer}
}

// Repository is a structure holding a slice of Sourcer
type Repository struct {
    DataSource []Sourcer
}

// Fetch tries fetching from the aggregated data source of the
// repository.
func (r Repository) Fetch(wg *sync.WaitGroup) chan []byte {
    ch := make(chan []byte, 1)

    // Spawn goroutines to Fetch from every source. Ignore the nil
    // source(s) even if it's Fetched before than the non-nil source.
    for i := range r.DataSource {
        fmt.Printf("Start fetching from: %s\n", r.DataSource[i].Name())
        go func(s Sourcer) {
            wg.Add(1)
            if d := s.Fetch(); d != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Fetched from: %s\n", s.Name())
                ch <- d
            }
            wg.Done()
        }(r.DataSource[i])
    }

    return ch
}

func main() {
    // Create a repository with data sources
    repository := new(Repository)

    // Add data sources to the repository
    // Format:
    // <source_name>: <data>, <minimum response time>
    //
    // sa: nil,     3s
    // sb: "dummy", 5s
    // sc: nil,     7s
    repository.DataSource = []Sourcer{
        NewSource("sa", nil, 3*time.Second),
        NewSource("sb", []byte("dummy"), 5*time.Second),
        NewSource("sc", nil, 7*time.Second),
    }

    // Create a context with deadline of 10m. If Fetch
    // takes more than 10m, Fetch is cancelled.
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}

    // Start fetching
    ch := repository.Fetch(wg)

    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Fetch:", Deadline)
        os.Exit(1)
    case d := <-ch:
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stdout, "Fetch:", string(d))
    }

    wg.Wait()
    close(ch)
}
```

Sample output:

```golang
Start fetching from: sa
Start fetching from: sb
Start fetching from: sc
Fetched from: sb
Fetch: dummy
```

Comment: channel will leak

Comment: Close it! For me, the program was getting terminated. Given your use case, "produce" to the channel and make the "producer"  close it after use.

Comment: It's better now. But in Golang there is one rule: channel should close who create it. I think that the issue is very popular pattern. But I don't know it's name and can't google it.

Comment: You are right. And that's why I wrote that the producer should close it. Here: https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/4 (Read the note). Also, read "The Channel Closing Principle" from: https://go101.org/article/channel-closing.html .

The reason is simple, sending on closed channel results in panic. That's why a sender should close and not a receiver. That's why I have handled the same by knowing when all the senders are done with their sends and now it's safe to close the channel.

Answer (score -2):

Not a complete answer, I just can't ask you:

Are you familiar with the select command?
it looks like case command, but selects from the available channels

https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/5 and 6

this may be what you are looking for